# Multiple Selection Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner that acts like a filter for searching among several categories. But the problem is that the spinner allows only one category to select from. Is there a way to obtain a multiple selection behavior for the spinner, or what other alternatives exists?

Comment: http://chrisblunt.com/2011/03/01/android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Spinner with multiple choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

Comment: stuck in same can anyone help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446088/how-to-get-spinner-values-in-textview/29487383?noredirect=1#comment47175570_29487383

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304

Answer (score 11, accepted):

S spinner is designed to show one item at a time. You might get away by making a spinner of checkboxes, but it will be probably an awful user experience.

I would suggest you a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead and [CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE). You can add a listview to a dialog as shown in this answer: [is it possible to create listview inside dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874191/is-it-possible-to-create-listview-inside-dialog/2874302#2874302)

Comment: Thanks , I'm going to give it a try !

Comment: stuck in same can anyone help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446088/how-to-get-spinner-values-in-textview/29487383?noredirect=1#comment47175570_29487383

Answer (score 7):

Android provides Spinner widget which has functionality similar to drop-down list. But Spinner accepts single selection. so we select only one item at a time.so We can achieve multi-select feature using a custom Pop-up Window with a multi-select list.
Pop-up window is similar to Dialogs except that a pop-up window can be positioned.

When the drop-down button is clicked a list will be displayed(as drop-down), then you can select multiple values. The selected values will be displayed in a Text box above the list.

for reference you can prefer this link:

http://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/

Comment: stuck in same can anyone help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446088/how-to-get-spinner-values-in-textview/29487383?noredirect=1#comment47175570_29487383