# Creating Arrays which can save text in android and be able to open them

Tags: android, arrays

Now I know this may be a lot to ask for. But what I want to do is have the ability to save and open notes. Now currently I am able to save and load data on the phone to be opened the next time the app is open with this code here:

```
public class Notes extends Activity{

EditText savedText;
TextView dataResults;
public static String stringFolder = "SharedData";
SharedPreferences String;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes);
    setupVariables();
    String = getSharedPreferences(stringFolder, 0);

}

private void setupVariables(){

    savedText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes_text_view);
    dataResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notes_text_view);

}   

public void saveNotes(View v)
{

    String stringData = savedText.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = String.edit();
    editor.putString("SharedData", stringData);
    editor.commit();
}

public void loadNotes(View v){
    String = getSharedPreferences(stringFolder, 0);
    String dataReturned = String.getString("SharedData", "Could not load");
    dataResults.setText(dataReturned);
}
```

Now what I am hoping to do is every time the user clicks save it adds the text entered into an array under a name which the user can enter. When the user clicks load I want a list view to pop up showing all the names of the notes which have previously been saved and click on one to load it. i know this is a lot to ask but I'm wondering if anyone out there knows. Or there might be a very simple way to do this. I am very much a beginner to android.

Thanks, Reid

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to display a dialog with EditText on saving and a dialog with ListView on loading. Basics on creating dialogs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874191/is-it-possible-to-create-listview-inside-dialog).