# using spinner on ListView with Sql lite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, spinner

My android app contains a list view that shows the data base context. This is what I want:

1-When the list view row gets clicked (itemClickListener),the custom spinner shows.

2-When a spinner item is selected, the title of it is shown in the list view fields.

3-At last: The color of the rows change, when an item is selected.

I've found a solution for no.1 in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889938/3671748) but I don't know about the other two. Would you please help me to solve these problems ?

Comment: hey mina, you should handle the items with `setOnItemClickListener` and when one item selected, do something.(you can do this with Switch statement for each item).injor soal porsidan kasi javab nemide ;) and for title showing,set an adaptor and then pass it from db into the listview.

Comment: @AndroidDev.i use switch , but I don't know the connection between them.i use base adapter for my adapter. (khahesh mikonam man dar zamine kar ba db kam tajrobeam- va hanuz in tavanaee ra nadaram. lotfan pasokh soalam ra bedahid)

Comment: @AndroidDev. lets start a chat for resolving it,please.